# How to achieve the correct posture if you're short, get a shorter stand or higher chair?

Tags: piano, beginner, posture

I bought a digital piano with a fixed height stand and the top of the key are 28.75 inches from the ground. I need to get my elbow to be parallel with the key height, is what I got from online videos. So either I get an adjustable stand and set it at a lower height or get an adjustable chair and set it at a greater height (and be sort of standing). I've been using a dining room chair and my thigh is parallel when I sit on that chair. My elbows are about 25 inches from the ground when seated. I'm not sure what's the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Adjustable stand
2. Adjustable chair/bench
3. Sit forward on the chair, so your feet can be flat on the floor
4. Footrest

In my experience, #3 is the most common issue, and the easiest and cheapest to fix. Pianists should sit as close to the front edge of the chair/bench as is comfortable. This allows for weight in our feet on the floor or footrest, which supports our back. It also makes it easier to move when we need to play in the high or low registers of the instrument.

Comment: It seems to me I would need to raise my seat another 2 inches. Hopefully I would still be seated somewhat.

Comment: @udeleng Allowing you would also be sitting at the front edge of your seat, lowering the keyboard would be a better option that raising your chair.

Answer (score 1):

The two factors that are important are elbow height compared to keyboard level, but also feet on the floor. Let's be stupid: you could raise yourself and the keyboard another 6", and the arms wouldn't change. But your feet would be dangling!

So, let's start where the floor is.Heels resting on it, so you can work the pedal/s comfortably. Sitting (not slouched) will give you the elbow height, so then the keyboard height can be adjusted. I prefer elbows sligtly higher than the 'board, so gravity will help lower arms/wrists/hands when needed - most of the time.

Comment: Do shorter people playing at a real piano use a a higher seat + foot rest or how do they do it or do they semi-stand on the seat edge?

Comment: @udeleng - they tend to saw off the bottom of the legs of the stool. Then they have to do the same with the piano...  Or they could even use a raised board on the floor for their feet, which would get in the way of the pedals. Or take up a different instrument..!

Answer (score 1):

Real pianos aren't adjustable.

Real piano stools ARE adjustable.

Unless this keyboard is the only one you'll ever play, I suggest you get used to a standard height instrument and an adjustable stool.   (Or sit on some books.)

Comment: Maybe higher floors?

Comment: Indeed.  Or stilts.